# Swift Optional chaining

Tags: ios, swift

This code is from Apple's new book.  My question is: How come "let roomCount = john.residence?.numberOfRooms" is nil, I thought .numberOfRooms should be 1 but in xcode it says is nil I just don't get why is nil.  If anyone can clarify me this that would be awesome.  Thank you in advance.

```
class Person {
    var residence: Residence?
}

class Residence {
    var numberOfRooms = 1
}

let john = Person()

let roomCount = john.residence?.numberOfRooms

john.residence = Residence()

john.residence?.numberOfRooms


if let roomCount = john.residence?.numberOfRooms {
    print("John's residence has \(roomCount) room(s).")
} else {
    print("Unable to retrieve the number of rooms.")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`residence` is not initialised yet when you are trying to use it with:

```
let roomCount = john.residence?.numberOfRooms
```

So this will always print `nil` because `residence` have nothing to return.

If you want to use `.numberOfRooms` first initialise your `residence` instance and use it this way:

```
let john = Person()
john.residence = Residence()
let roomCount = john.residence?.numberOfRooms  // 1
```

One more way to do it is initialise it into your `Person` class:

```
class Person {
    var residence = Residence()
}
```

Now you can use `.numberOfRooms` this way:

```
let john = Person()
let roomCount = john.residence.numberOfRooms  // 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how come when I type "let roomCount = john.residence?.numberOfRooms" I have access to .numberOfRooms and not the value I assigned which is 1.  Sorry I am confused I just don't get it.

Comment: because `numberOfRooms ` is a property of  `Residence` class thats why you can access it with `.`

Comment: Yes but that property has a value of 1 and I just don't get why is nil when that property has a value of 1.

Comment: I get it now because Residence hasn't been initialized and that's why residence is nil and .numberOfRooms is nil too and after john.residence = Residence() is not nil anymore.  It took me a while to get it.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

```
let roomCount = john.residence?.numberOfRooms
```

in this line the roomCount have to be nil because you didn't set the residence instance variable.
roomCount is not nil when it comes after john.residence = Residance().

Okey so

```
let roomCount = john.residence?.numberOfRooms
```

is like this

```
let roomCount: Int! = nil

if let unwrappedResidence = john.residence
{
    roomCount = unwrappedResidence.numberOfRooms
}
```

So If residence is nil, the roomCount is being nil.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But how come it has access to .numberOfRooms?

Comment: It doesn't have access to number of rooms. That is the point of the optional chaining. It only has access to number of rooms if residence isn't nil. If residence is nil then room count will be nil. If you said `let roomCount=john.residence!.numberOfRooms` you would get an unexpectedly found nil runtime exception

Answer (score 2):

In the example, line `let john = Person()` creates a object *john* of type *Person*.

*Person* type consist of optional property *residence* i.e. `var residence: Residence?`

Here *residence* is **nil** because Type *Residence* is not initialized yet. But one can access its property *numberOfRooms* even *residence* is nil (because here **Optional Chaining** is used) and result of accessing it, is nil

```
let roomCount = john.residence?.numberOfRooms
```

Afterward when *residence* is initialized and assigned,

```
john.residence = Residence()
```

Now, *john.residence* object is initialized and when accessing its *numberOfRooms* property, it returns default assigned value 1.

In swift, properties are accessible for optional types whether they are nil or not (initialized or not initialized).

> **Optional Chaining**
>
> Optional chaining is a process for querying and calling properties, methods, and subscripts on an optional that **might currently be nil**. If the optional contains a value, the property, method, or subscript call succeeds; **if the optional is nil, the property, method, or subscript call returns nil**. Multiple queries can be chained together, and the entire chain fails gracefully if any link in the chain is nil.

[Find reference here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)